# How to count chars in field onload?

Tags: javascript, input

I have this script that counts chars left to write in a input field. But it starts counts after I start writing.

I would like it to show chars left when page loads though my input fields already contains text.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function textCounter( field, countfield, maxlimit ) {
 if ( field.value.length > maxlimit ) {
  field.value = field.value.substring( 0, maxlimit );
  field.blur();
  field.focus();
  return false;
 } else {
  countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
 }
}
</script>

<input TYPE=text NAME=mytext value="<?=$mytext?>" onblur="textCounter(this,this.form.counter1,50);" onkeyup="textCounter(this,this.form.counter1,50);" > 
            <input onblur="textCounter(this.form.recipients,this,50);" disabled  onfocus="this.blur();" tabindex="999" maxlength="2" size="2" value="50" name="counter1"> chars left
```

Comment: Just explicitly call `textCounter` after the elements are available.

Comment: I'm no good at javascript. Can you please give me anexample how to?

Comment: Thank you! It seem to work well :)
The only thing ias that I have 16 inputs I need to chek, so I need to do ...
document.onload=textCounter(document.getElementById('a1'),document.getElementById('b1'),50);

document.onload=textCounter(document.getElementById('c1'),document.getElementById('d1'),50);

etc .... 16 times, but that's ok :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the function by `onblur="textCounter(this.form.recipients,this,50);` which executes the function when a user leaves the input field and `onkeyup="textCounter(this,this.form.counter1,50);` which executes a JavaScript when the user releases a key.

If you want to show the chars left when page loads, Just call it after the page loaded.

```
document.onload=textCounter(document.getElementById('a'),
                            document.getElementById('b'),50);
```

Here is the example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bx4mW/)